# Azure AD Connect or Cloud Sync Alternatives

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently Azure AD only receives identity information through AD Connect.  While this works and needs to remain in place, it obviously requires the data to be populated into AD first, which can present challenges from a technical and workflow aspect. If the data is only needed in Azure AD and not in on-prem AD then having to send the data through AD first increases the level of effort for adding new data to Azure AD.

Does Azure AD supports sources in addition to AD Connect or Cloud Sync for attribute population? We want to be able to sync certain data to Azure AD without having to ensure the data is present in our on-prem AD first.

Answer (score 0):

If the user (or another identity) is required only in the cloud, you can create it in your Azure AD.

The is that you could only manage that identity in your Azure AD.

Azure AD Connect allows password writeback and groups writeback, you cannot sync anything else beyond that.